# using array_rand rather than shuffle in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am using the code from this [grade.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627482/php-quiz-array-to-be-displayed-randomly). I would like to use `array_Rand` than using shuffle. Can anyone please help?

The code works fine but I would like to show maybe like 10 out of 20 questions instead hence using `shuffle()` isn't really what I wanted. Would appreciate any help I could get, thank you in advance!

Edit: I added the Array_slice and now is showing error :

> Undefined index: Questions @ line 77

Comment: Could you just use `array_slice` to get the first 10 shuffled questions? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: `array_rand($Questions, 10);`...

Comment: @jibsteroos yes i tried but i do not know how to manipulate the foreach loop. Please advice many thanks!

Comment: @benJ Will i need to edit the foreach loop when echo the question and options out? As i am having trouble manipulating the code there. Please advice. Thank you

Comment: @benJ I tried it and i get  **Undefined index: Questions at line 77 **  i have edited the code in question please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick Ids and then intersect the original array.  Here is an example picking two at random:

```
<?php    
$questions = array(
    1 => array(
        'Question' => '1. CSS stands for',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'Computer Styled Sections',
            'B' => 'Cascading Style Sheets',
            'C' => 'Crazy Solid Shapes'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'B'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'Question' => '2. What is the Capital of the Philippines',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'Cebu City',
            'B' => 'Davao City',
            'C' => 'Manila City'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'C'
    ),
    3 => array(
        'Question' => '3. What is black and white',
        'Answers' => array(
            'A' => 'A Zebra',
            'B' => 'A Sycamore Tree',
            'C' => 'Law'
        ),
        'CorrectAnswer' => 'A'
    )
);

$rand_ids       = array_rand($questions, 2);
$rand_questions = array_intersect_key($questions, array_flip($rand_ids));
```

Comment: Upon form submission get the keys from your submitted answers (that pertain to the ids here) and you can use them to intersect your questions array for the same subset.